# SQL Server : Bulk Insert 0 Rows Affected

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I'm new to SQL and I'm attempting to do a bulk insert into a view, however, when I execute the script the message says (0 row(s) affected).

This is what I'm executing:

```
BULK INSERT vwDocGeneration
FROM '\\servername\Data\Doc\Test.csv'
WITH
( 
    Fieldterminator = '|',
    Rowterminator = '\r\n'
)
```

I've confirmed the row terminators in my source file and they end with CRLF. The view and the file being imported have the same number of columns. I'm stuck! Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't insert records into a view. You'll need to modify the tables that the view pulls from.

Comment: @Jared_S . . . Of course you can `bulk insert` into a view (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx).  It is the only way to get identity columns to work properly.

Comment: Inserting data into a view - is tricky. Best case, it creates a lot more scope for errors. You can't insert data that affects more than one base table, so it's usually simpler just to insert into that.

Comment: @Mike K I attempted to bulk insert the data into the primary table before trying the view and I get the same message.  *sigh

Comment: @DebbyPulido: in that case, it's probably the same error that's stopping it from inserting now. You need to troubleshoot that error first - most likely a key constraint of some sort. Can you insert individual rows into that table?

Comment: @Mike K you were spot on! I made a change on my primary key and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Mike K 's suggestion I started looking at key constraints and after I adjusted on of them I was able to use the bulk insert! FYI I did insert into the view because the table had an additional field that wasn't included in my CSV file. Thanks for confirming its possible @Gordon Linoff.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for the number of rows affected by that operation, then use this.

```
DECLARE @Rows int
DECLARE @TestTable table (col1 int, col2 int)

// your bulk insert operation

SELECT @Rows=@@ROWCOUNT
SELECT @Rows AS Rows,@@ROWCOUNT AS [ROWCOUNT]
```

Or you can first bulk insert into a table, then create an appropriate view from that table.

Following article might be useful -

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/236425/How-to-insert-data-using-SQL-Views-created-using-m

Comment: Thanks for the references!  I'm looking for a way to get the CSV into the SQL table, either the main table or the view.  I am just having trouble because it doesn't error out.  It just doesn't do anything.